# llamar una variable en otro php sin get ni post

Tags: php, variables

muchas gracias a la comunidad de antemano.
bueno al asunto, he creado un select option dinamico sencillo que al seleccionar un cliente en el siguiente select option salen sus mascotas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui cargo en el primer select option los clientes.

```
<label for="inputEmail1" required class="col-lg-2 control-label">Paciente:</label>
<select id="id_paciente" name="id_paciente" class="form-control" onchange="MostrarMascota()">
<option value="" selected disabled>---SELECCIONE---</option>
<?php
$salx=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pacientes ");  

while($col=mysql_fetch_array($salx)){
echo '<option value="'.$col['id'].'">'.$col['nombre'].'</option>';
                         }
 ?>
```

y el de mascotas es el siguiente codigo:

```
   </select>
  <br>
   <label for="inputEmail1" required class="col-lg-2 control-label">Mascotas:</label>
   <div  id="div_mascot">
   <select name="mascotas" type=text  id="mascotas" autocomplete="off"     class="form-control"  required>
<option value=""></option> 
</select>
   </div>
   <br>
```

Para que saliera las mascotas del cliente tuve que realizar otro php que realice la respectiva consulta con el id ya obtenido por un get.
Este seria el codigo que menciono:

```
<select name="mascotas" id="mascotas" class="form-control">
<option value="">- Seleccione Mascota -</option>
<?php
     include '/conexion.php';
     $IdEspe = $_POST['id'];
   $sql = "select mascotas.id, mascotas.nombre from mascotas where     idpaciente= $IdEspe";
      $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
      {
        $idcitass=$row['id'];
     ?>
    <option  value="<?php echo $row['id']."~".$row['nombre'] ?>" ><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></option>
    <?php
       $valor=explode("~",$_POST["mascotas"]);
        $clase=$valor[0];
        $clase2=$valor[1];
     }
     ?>
 </select>
```

se hizo un select option que tiene dos variables por valor separados por el signo ~. El problema que tengo es que al querer manipular las variables $clase y $clase2 al otro php por medio de un include "combomascota.php"; me sale error en la pagina y no tengo idea como obtener esas dos variables en el otro php.

Comment: Si agregas el error que te muestra la página es más fácil poder ayudarte

Comment: Por que no quieres ocupar Get o Post? porque tu variable es compuesta por $row['id']."~".$row['nombre']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no me parece una opción valida utilizar variables de `SESSION` para tu ejemplo,

> Las sesiones siguen un flujo de trabajo sencillo. Cuando una sesión se inicia, PHP recuperará una sesión existente usando el ID pasado (normalmente desde una cookie de sesión) o, si no se pasa una sesión, se creará una sesión nueva. PHP rellenará la variable superglobal $_SESSION con cualesquiera datos de la sesión iniciada. Cuando PHP se cierra, automáticamente toma el contenido de la variable superglobal $_SESSION, la serializa, y la envía para almacenarla usando el gestor de almacenamiento de sesiones.

**EDIT**

Tu selector mascotas tiene un id `id="mascotas"`, la unica manera que puedas leer y manipular el valor de la seleccion que dio el usuario es DESPUES de la petición `GET` o `POST`.

Tu HTML es de lado cliente mientras que tu logica PHP es del lado servidor..

Lo que debes hacer en tu OTRO archivo `PHP` que es al cual haces post es

Pagina HTML del formulario

```
<select name="mascotas" id="mascotas" class="form-control">
<option value="">- Seleccione Mascota -</option>
<?php
  include '/conexion.php';
  $IdEspe = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = "select mascotas.id, mascotas.nombre from mascotas where     idpaciente= $IdEspe";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $idcitass=$row['id'];
        echo '<option   value="'.$row["id"]."~".$row["nombre"].'" >'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
  }
?>
</select>
```

Y ahi trabajarla.

Archivo PHP

```
$valor=explode("~",$_POST["mascotas"]);
$clase=$valor[0];
$clase2=$valor[1];
```

**EDIT 2**

Te dejo un link con un ejemplo de lo que tu estas haciendo, puedes inspeccionar elemento y verificar que los id y values son los que tu quieres.

[Ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hkuz-p8mm)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta @sioesi, tu codigo funciona correctamente, el problema es que el archivo que modificastes es el primero que se carga entonces esas variables estarán vacías, es decir que los input hidden se están cargando cuando el select option mascota esta vacio y cuando ya tiene datos no cargan los otros input :S

Comment: Ya entendi lo que dices, editare mi respuesta!

Comment: @jota editado! ...

Comment: Amigo gracias por su ayuda, ahora el problema es que solo me muestra el ultimo dato de las opciones en mascotas por ejemplo: balto,lupita,titi. y selecciono balto me muestra en los input titi con su id, pero no el que selecciono siempre el ultimo. ud podria saber a que se debe eso ?

Comment: No deberia ocurrir eso, ya que las opciones se crean dentro de un ciclo...

Comment: lo que pasa es que el que carga el select de mascota no esta en un formulario lo cree en otro php por eso no puedo jalar esos datos que estan en ese php porque no uso form action :(

Comment: Como? Lo que yo veo en tu codigo es que haces una consulta a tu base de datos y recorres los resultados, por cada iteracion creas una opcion dentro de un select...

Answer (score 1):

Aunque no uses POST o GET para pasar los datos de un archivo php a otro, tendrás que usar un formulario para que el usuario recoja los datos igualmente, pero si aun así no quieres usar ninguna de de esas formas para pasarlo a otro archivo, lo mejor es usar sesiones.

En tu código se ven elementos que tienen que estar dentro de un formulario, pero no se ve la declaración de ningún formulario

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <!-- aquí los elementos del form -->
</form>
```

Una vez que hayas construido bien tu formulario, solo tienes que validarlo y procesarlo.

```
if(isset($_POST["send"])) {

    if(isset($_POST["paciente"]) && isset($_POST["mascotas"])) {

        session_start();
        $_SESSION["paciente"] = $_POST["paciente"];
        $_SESSION["mascotas"] = $_POST["mascotas"];
    }

}
```

Luego para acceder a los datos desde cualquier otra página solo tienes que volver a usar `session_start()` en cada página donde quieras acceder a las variables de sesión

```
session_start();
```

y ya podrás acceder a tus variables de sesión `$_SESSION["paciente"]` y `$_SESSION["mascotas"]`